# Maximum of votes per day bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, votes

I noticed a particular issue today:

<kbd>[image: upvote attempt]</kbd>

From this screeshot you can tell that I could not upvote this question because I reached the daily vote limit.

However, by checking the vox populi badge:

<kbd>[image: vox populi badge]</kbd>

I am 2 votes away from the daily limit... I remember I have reached the daily vote limit at least one other time before, so this is not a new bug for me/my account.

I wonder what happened with the counting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you can only vote thirty times but you gain up to ten extra votes by voting on questions rather than answers.

From [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90202/153355):

> 1. Everyone gets a total of 30 votes.
> 2. You may get up to 10 extra question votes.
> 3. Warnings remain simple... (*5 votes remaining*, *4 votes remaining*...)
> 4. Question votes may be cast at any time during the day. However, once you reach the *N votes remaining* warnings, stuff is set in stone. A question voting spree at the end will still count down.

Comment: Oh... I probably voted in more answers than questions then... Thanks! I'll focus on questions tomorrow and report.

Comment: I got it! Upvoted more questions than answers this time :)